# Function for approximating a sine signal

Tags: c, embedded

I want to approximate a sine signal with a parabola, which is given by the function:

$$f(x) = 0.4053 \cdot x \cdot (3.1415 - x) \space\text{for}\space 0 \le x \le 3.1415$$

In a first approach, I wrote the following code which works fine:

```
float sin1(int phase)
{
    if(phase % 1000 <= 500)
    {
    return(0.4053*2*3.1415*(phase % 1000)/1000*(3.1415 - 2*3.1415*(phase % 1000)/1000));
    }
    else
    {
    return(-0.4053*2*3.1415*(phase % 500)/1000*(3.1415 - 2*3.1415*(phase % 500)/1000));
    }
}
```

As I want to use this function on a microcontroller, I'm interested in how to optimize this code regarding memory consumption and performance.

Comment: Any specific microcontroller?

Comment: The `phase` is given as thousandths of a radian?

Comment: Looks like 1000 phase = 1 revolution, so a phase is 0.36 degrees, or 18/pi radians.

Comment: is `phase` guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: Yes, it's positive.

Comment: I want to use an ARM Cortex M0.

Comment: Just as a general rule, please indent...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> how to optimize this code regarding memory consumption and performance. (?)

1. Consider redefining the angle measurement.  It appears `int phase` is [0.36 degrees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183451/function-for-approximating-a-sine-signal#comment349249_183451).  A natural choice would be *1024 `phase` to 1 revolution*.  Now the problem becomes one using a [binary angle measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling#Binary_angles). Not only does this simplify small things like scaling, it opens up coding choices  as there are many trig function code bases designed withs BAMS, *Binary Angular Measurement System*.
2. Code uses `double` constants and so makes for likely slower computation on an embedded system.  If all that is needed is `float`, uses `float` constants and `float` math.

   ```
   // return(0.4053*2*3.1415*(phase % 1000)/1000*(3.1415 - ...
   return(0.4053f*2*3.1415f*(phase % 1000)/1000*(3.1415f ...
   ```
3. OP reports `phase` guaranteed to be positive. yet it is minor to adjust code for full `int` range.

   ```
   // if(phase % 1000 <= 500)
   phase %= 1000;
   if (phase < 0) phase += 1000;
   if (phase <= 500)
   ```
4. Accuracy: Using `3.1415` for machine_pi can be improved at no computational cost by using  `#define MACHINE_PI 3.141592653589793f`.  This will improve the end points in the 5th or 6th decimal place.  Use `0.405284734572655f` instead of `0.4053` to insure `sine(90° (250 phase))` is `1.0f`.
5. If your processor lacks a built-in FP hardware, I recommend a fast integer only solution.  e.g. [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) or a small linear interpolation should only low precision be needed.

---

Using a parabola model like OP's  (1 cycle = 1024 BAM).  The below code is effectively the same preciseness as OP's code with only integer math: and, or, `+`, `-`, `*`, negate and shift.

Input  range [0<sup>R</sup> 2π<sup>R</sup>]  mapped to [0 to 1024]
Output range [-1.0 1.0] mapped to [-16,384 16,384]

```
int_fast16_t sin_bam(int angle_bam) {
  angle_bam %= 1024;
  if (angle_bam < 0)
    angle_bam += 1024;
  uint_fast16_t sub_angle = angle_bam % (1024u / 2);
  int_fast16_t sn = unsigned_mult16x16_into_32(sub_angle, (1024/2 - sub_angle)) / 4;
  if (angle_bam & 512) {
    sn = -sn;
  }
  return sn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That will surely help me a lot. I'm just trying to understand and compile your code. Could you please explain what exactly "unsigned_mult16x16_into_32" means and how to implement this?

Comment: @Peter123 Judging by the name, it multiplies two `uint_fast16_t`s and return a `uint_fast32_t`. You can implement it as such, anyway.

Comment: Peter123 @wizzwizz4  is correct.  `unsigned_mult16x16_into_32()` is a fictional name for a function that multiples 2 unsigned 16-bit integers and forms the 32 bit unsigned product.    Embedded compilers often have such an optimal function. Else could use `(uint32_t)a*b` or the like.

Comment: Thanks! In my application, I sometimes need to get an output range mapped to [-a a] with an arbitrary positive integer a. Do you see any possibility to do that without using floating point math?

Comment: @Peter123 Let `P = 1024`, the period and  `int_fast16_t sn = ... / m;`, with `m==4`, the amplitude `a` is 16384.  For a different amplitude, `m = (P/4)*(P/4)/a;`  If quotient `m` is not a whole number, use some integer scaling.

Comment: I'd replace the multiple instances of `1024` here with a constant (including the hidden instance listed as `512`

Answer (score 8):

here are the programming principles you ought to be applying:

1. Don't repeat yourself

   Note that the two statements (*statement-true* & *statement-false*) are just about the same as each other. If there's a mistake in one and you fix it, you might not fix it correctly in the other. So you really should have just one copy of the formula. This is even more critical on a microcontroller as you want to have the shortest code, right?
2. Don't repeat yourself

   Hmm, sounds familiar. Looks like you have `phase % 1000` multiple places. You should do it just once, into a temporary variable e.g. `int phase_mod_1000`, unless you are completely critical about avoiding temporary storage. I bet that freeing up that `float` will be worth it. And also note, `phase % 500` is just going to be `phase_mod_1000 - 500`. So three divisions turn into one. The optimizer might be able to do this automatically; this is really just to simplify the code. You should probably have constants (`#define`) for `PHASES_PER_CYCLE` and `PHASES_PER_HALFCYCLE`.
3. Don't do additional work

   I'm sure someone with a good sense of algebra could simplify the arithmetic, but guess what, the optimizer can too. Your compiler has a good optimizer, right?

Answer (score 7):

> I'm interested in how to optimize this code regarding memory consumption and performance.

Well, which is it? Are you optimizing for speed, ram, or executable size? You say this is for an embedded project, so it’s likely you’ll need to pick one.

Once I needed to calculate a sine wave for a motion controller. The timing was critical, but we had plenty of ROM and enough RAM that we just included a [pre-calculated table of sin values](http://math2.org/math/trig/tables.htm). They never change, so there’s no need to perform an expensive calculation at runtime, particularly if you’re in a timing sensitive function.

I honestly can’t tell if you’re calculating the same values or not, but the principle still applies I think. You only need this code long enough to calculate the values once, so it’s quality is a moot point (so long as it’s bug free).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sine there is a better way with only one multiply per step.

```
Let const P = the phase increment = 2 * pi * f * dt
Let const A = the amplitude
Let const H = 2 cos(P) (you only need to calculate H once, maybe by hand)
```

(note H is slightly less than 2)

```
Initialize V=0 and W=A*cos(P) = A*H/2

Loop: output V, X = W*H-V, V=W, W=X
```

So the only multiply is W*H, plus one subtraction and three assignments.

V and W are your first and second points, X is the next point etc.
You do have to take a cosine once, to initialize H

If you need a lot of cosines you might want to check out the CORDIC algorithm
(see Wikipedia)

Comment: BTW compared to a lookup table, you would still need to multiply by amplitude, so I don't bother with a LUT.  I just calculate the sine.

Comment: PS this sine wave may start to diverge after many cycles due to numerical error so it's best to run it for one cycle only then re-initialize.